# why jms Client acknowledge is not working

Tags: spring-boot, jms

I am trying to retrieve messages from an ActiveMQ queue. I set the session to `Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE`. When I receive the message from the server it is auto-acknowledged although I have not called acknowledge on the message. Below is sample code of what I am doing:

```java
connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
Destination destination = session.createQueue(queue);
consumer = session.createConsumer(destination);
connection.start();
Message message = consumer.receive(1);
```

The code snippet above works and I do get the message from the queue. The problem is that messages disappear from the queue although I have not acknowledged the message. Any pointers why this is happening. I have been debugging this issue almost all this afternoon with no luck. This is a Spring boot application.

I got the client_ack to work in jmsTemplate. Below is the code.

```
public Object retrieve() {
        return this.jmsTemplate.execute(session -> {
            session.recover();
            MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(
                    this.jmsTemplate.getDestinationResolver().resolveDestinationName(session, queue, false));
            try {
                Message received = consumer.receive(1);
                if (received != null) {
                    return this.messageConverter.fromMessage(received);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                return null;
            }
            finally {
                consumer.close();
            }
            return null;
        }, true);
    }
```

The issue I am now seeing is that my app does not see these messages after it restarts. I tried running session.recover() but it is not making any difference. Thanks for your help.

The working code using jmsTemplate is as below:

```
public Object retrieve() {
        return this.jmsTemplate.execute(session -> {
            MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(
                    this.jmsTemplate.getDestinationResolver().resolveDestinationName(session, queue, false));
            try {
                Message received = consumer.receive(1);
                session.recover();
                if (received != null) {
                    return this.messageConverter.fromMessage(received);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                return null;
            }
            finally {
                consumer.close();
            }
            return null;
        }, true);
    }
```

Comment: I am using 5.14.4 version. I am watching the queue from ActiveMQ management console. I don't see any messages in the queue after I run my code. I see same behavior in IBM MQ server also.

Comment: Thanks Justin. I am able to get jmsTemplate to work with client_ack but like you said, it seems like these messages cannot be seen in the queue although they now exist. 

This is the code that works with client_ack but as I said, when the app runs again, it cannot see the messages although they are in the queue. I will add this code in the post. Thanks again for looking into this.

Comment: I don't really understand what the problem is at this point. It looks like your original problem is gone, but you still reference it in your question. It seems like your problem now is completely different. Please clarify your question or it will probably get closed.

Comment: Hi Justin, thanks for looking into this. I got it resolved. I will post my findings in the post. The solution was to set session to non-transacted, execute session.recover() after pulling the message and lastly set the max number of redelivery to -1(no limit). -

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a problem with the springframework Constants class. It uses introspection to get the integer value of CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE but always return a value of 1, so session is always AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE

Answer (score 0):

To anybody who might run into this issue, I did the following to resolve the issue:

1. Set the session to non-transacted. This is the default and only option if you are using jmsTemplate. If you are creating your own consumer, you need to create the session as non-transacted when creating the jms connection
2. If you are creating your own consumer, you need to set the session to CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE.
3. Check the maximum number of redeliveries to the required value. This will differ depending on the product: ActiveMQ, IBM MQ, etc.
4. call session.recover() after retrieving the message.

I updated the working code that is using jmsTemplate in the original post.